# Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL Pool: How can I create an external table as select ( CETAS ) and partition by CustomerID?

Tags: azure-synapse-analytics

I can create CETAS tables in Azure Blob storage fairly easily ( [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) ), however, is there a simple way to automatically partition by CustomerID so that the rows associated with each customer will end up in their own folder?

Essentially I'm looking for a CETAS parameter that will cause my data to end up in folders like this:

```
Azure Blob Storage Container/
    CustomerTable/
        CustomerID=1/
            .parquet files for Customer 1
        CustomerID=2/
            .parquet files for Customer 2
        ...
        CustomerID=N/
            .parquet files for Customer N
```

(Note: I'm running around 10,000 CETAS statements on 100+ TB of data, I imagine I can change my script to look for tables that have a CustomerID column and manually partition the data by CustomerID, however, I was hoping there was some syntax with the CETAS statement that I could have the system partition the data for me).

Comment: I ended up doing this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not with CETAS.But you can try using Delta lake

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerTable
USING delta
PARTITIONED BY (CustomerID)
LOCATION 'abfss://<></>'
AS SELECT /*/ FROM <Externam TAble already created>
```

And then create a view of it

```
CREATE VIEW Customer.vwCustomerData
AS
SELECT *
FROM 
OPENROWSET(
        BULK '<></>',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'ExternalDataSourceDataLake',
        FORMAT='DELTA'
    ) dim
```

Note: External Table to be used

Comment: Do you have any links to the documentation showing CTAS with a USING or PARTITIONED BY clauses?  I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7 but I don't see the documentation on how to use it?  (When I tried what you suggested I get Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'USING'.